# Swift SpriteKit Gravity Point

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I need to make something like a Gravity Point in Swift. 
The SpriteNode is in the middle of the screen, and by Left or Right Gestures it can move along the x-axis.

But after for e.g. a 'RightSwipe', it should come back to his starting point. You could say it should look like a jump along the x-axis.

The World Gravity cant be a specific point, so how can I 'Force' it to come back to his original point?

I tried it with SKFieldNode's RadialGravityField, but after the Nodes impulse is made, it goes back to his original point and disappears.
How can I avoid that?

My Code:

```
{ 
.......

Node = SKSpriteNode(texture: Node1)
Node.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 140)
Node.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 4)
Node.zPosition = 3
Node.runAction(RunAnimation)

Node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Node.size)
Node.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
Node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
Node.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
Node.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
Node.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

self.addChild(Node)

let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("SwipeRight:"))
swipeRight.direction = .Right
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("SwipeLeft:"))
swipeLeft.direction = .Left
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}

func SwipeRight(recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

Node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10,0))

}

func SwipeLeft(recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

Node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-10,0))

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

if(Node.position.x > self.frame.size.width / 1.6)
    {
        fieldNode = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()
        fieldNode.enabled = true
        fieldNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 4)
        fieldNode.strength = 0.4
        addChild(fieldNode)
    }

    if(Node.position.x < self.frame.size.width / 2.6)
    {
        fieldNode = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()
        fieldNode.enabled = true
        fieldNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 4)
        fieldNode.strength = 0.4
        addChild(fieldNode)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a radial gravity `SKFieldNode`. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/radialGravityField)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it now with the radial gravity instead of the springfield, and after the node is at his origin point, it disappears. I added the code.

Comment: I implemented your code but the sprite is so large that it barely moves when I swipe.

Comment: same here, it just disappears.

Comment: I guess when it reaches centre of force field, force acting on that object goes as high as infinity because f=strength/r^2 and r=0, so now force = very very high, so object is suddenly put at infinity